# Sapien PowerShell Studio 2014 Create button to open outlook email draft

Tags: email, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to find the code for a button that will open an email dialog with the 'send' and 'subject' already filled in, so the customer can just click send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean open the default email client?

```
Start-Process "mailto:someone@example.org?subject=Testing"
```